# Foucault currents with a simple pendulum

Tags: forces, magnetic-fields, electrons, electric-current

I have this diagram :

[image]

It's a kind of pendulum; when it swings, it passes through a small aera where there is a magnetic field. Therefore, the electrons moves towards the bottom because of a Lorentz force.
I thought the Foucault current was due to a Laplace force but it would only explain the electrons' motion to the left and not the one to the right.

I think I'm missing something here because I understood well the Foucault current concept with a magnet who falls in a copper tube.
Could someone explain me the Foucault current concept in that case ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally I wrote this as a comment to ask for clarification but I think it might qualify as an answer (if I interpret your question correctly).

I see two magnetic effects: electrons moving in the region of strong magnetic field feel the vertical force; and to the left / right you have an increase / decrease in magnetic field (as you enter / leave the strong magnetic field area) which results in eddy currents (the metal sets up a current to resist the change in imposed field).

Is that in fact what you were asking about? It wasn't completely clear.

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding (as a French, that was pretty hard to explain). Yes, you are actually right. I first thought that induced currents were only applying to close electric circuits and coils. So it seems that it also applies to metals and that kind of things. Thank you

Comment: Eddy currents in metals are very important. It's for example why transformer cores are made from lamina rather than solid blocks of iron - it limits the current flow and thus heating losses. "Induction heating" (where you cook with RF) is based on the same principle of induced eddy currents (which is the usual English word for "courant de Foucault", incidentally).